# Cómo vincular propiedades de la Tubla como DataSource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, tuplas

Tengo una duda con el funcionamiento de las [Tuplas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.tuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), dependiendo de la forma en la que la inicialice, me funciona correctamente o no.

Me gusta este tema de las [Tuplas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.tuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8), ya que me permite agrupar información sin tener que escribir una estructura o clase para esto, *sin embargo no tengo mucha experiencia trabajando con tuplas*.

Ahora intentaré detallar mi duda:

Suponiendo que tengo la siguiente clase:

```
class TipoDocumento
{
      public string Codigo { get; set; }
      public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}

//Que podría usar así: 
List<TipoDocumento> lista = new List<TipoDocumento>
{
      new TipoDocumento { Codigo = "C", Descripcion = "C - Cédula" },
      new TipoDocumento { Codigo = "P", Descripcion = "P - Pasaporte" },
      new TipoDocumento { Codigo = "N", Descripcion = "N - Nss" }
};
```

Más bien podría crear una Tupla semejante a esta:

```
var lista = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
{
    Tuple.Create("C", "C - Cédula"),
    Tuple.Create("P", "P - Pasaporte"),
    Tuple.Create("N", "N - Nss")
};
```

La cual puedo asignar en este caso a un ComboBoxEdit (Componente DevExpress):

```
//ComboEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Descripcion"; ///Cuando trabajo con la lista de la clase
//ComboEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Codigo"; ///Cuando trabajo con la lista de la clase
ComboEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Item2"; ///Con la Tupla
ComboEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Item1"; //Con la Tupla
ComboEdit1.Properties.DataSource = lista;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Sin embargo, esto parece ser un poco redundante, repetir tanto la sintaxis `new TipoDocumento` o `Tuple.Create`

---

Así que seguí leyendo sobre las tuplas y veo que hay mejores forma de inicializaras:

```
var lista = new (string Codigo, string Descripcion)[]
{
      ("C", "C - Cédula"),
      ("P", "P - Pasaporte"),
      ("N", "N - Nss")
};

var lista = new List<(string Codigo, string Descripcion)>
{
      ("C", "C - Cédula"),
      ("P", "P - Pasaporte"),
      ("N", "N - Nss")
};
```

Que bien podría acceder a ellas así: `lista[0].Codigo` y `lista[0].Descripcion`
y esto efectivamente es una forma correcta de inicilializarlas, pero no me reconoce los valores el `ComboBoxEdit` al hacer tal cual hago en lo anterior:

> `ComboEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Descripcion";` No funciona
>    `ComboEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Codigo";` No funciona
>    `ComboEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Item2";` No funciona
>    `ComboEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Item1";` No funciona
>
> Esto si funciona obviamente, reconoce que tiene una fuente de datos asignada. Pero no muestra los valores...
>    `ComboEdit1.Properties.DataSource = lista;`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Entonces la pregunta sería: **Por qué no me permite utilizar la tupla para mostrar los valores, tal y como funciona con la clase o `Tuple.Create`?.
Cómo debo asignarla?**

> Esto no es un tema de vida o muerte, tampoco me esta causando error, pero **me causa intriga saber por qué no me funciona de esta menera** 
>   *Creo que fueron muchos detalles para una pregunta tan simple, pero es mejor ser claro!*

Entorno: Visual Studio 2017 & .NetFrameWork 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Que tonto soy, el propio título de mi pregunta contiene la respuesta! - "propiedades"*

Ahora que veo sucede que para `Tuple` de la forma antigua (Antes de C# 7) todos los elementos de la tupla son **propiedades** y por lo tanto es por esto que la Tupla que contiene la sintaxis: `Tuple.Create` si es vinculable.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.item1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Mientras que para `ValueTuple` todos sus elementos son **campos** y no pueden ser enlazables. Ya que el enlace de datos estándar de Windows Forms solo funciona con propiedades.

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8